# C#, Visual Studio 2010, LINQ Join Multiple Datatable

Tags: c#, linq, join, datatable

I've got quite a problem I cant seem to get my head around. From the start... I have three database tables: Now i'm pulling them into DATATABLES in the c# paorgram. These dt's are called inventory and items.

```
|-----------------|   |------------------|
|  - Inventory -  |   |   - Items -      |
|-----------------|   |------------------|
|     slot1       |   |     itemid       |
|      qty1       |   |    itemname      |
|     slot2       |   | item description |
|      qty2       |   |------------------|
|-----------------|
```

in inventory - slot1 contains an item id. 
in inventory - qty 1 contains quantity.

items should be fairly self explantiory.

In sql im sure i'd perform a join on items where slot 1 = ""... i think?

Anyway, what i want to do is find out what the itemid, name and description of the item in slot 1. I hope you understand what im asking for... P.S i have already searched google.. for about 6 hours almost and everytime i get close to what i think will work it just doesnt. I know exactly what i want to do, i just have no idea how to go about it! Also, im sure its going to have to be a LINQ as you cant run sql on datatables in c# :/

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you looking for something like follow:

```
from c in Inventory
   from item in Items
     where item.ID = c.Slot
       select new {c.Slot, item.name, c....}
```

This is simple startup with EF (I think is too much better than Dataset, ....):
http://entityframeworktutorial.net/create-first-simple-EDM.aspx#.UUTNmjfxfXw

I selected small part of toturial to learn how to make your first sample, after you see this you can try code first.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the speedy reply. I get an error, " could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'Syste.Data.DataTable'. 'SelectMany' not found.

Comment: I suggest you to show your exact data types, if you were using entity items from EF it will be ok.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, i have mixed datatypes. The datatables that are being filled from a database contain both varchar and int data fields.

Comment: Sorry, i've had no luck looking for a solution for EF... Heres the code... 

     DataSet slot1 = new DataSet();

     var item1name = from itemname in inventory // Heres the error...
                     from item in items
                     where item.ID = c.Slot
                     select new {c.Slot, item.name, c....}

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: @NicholasMordecai, I'm really not sure, and is a long time I'm not playing with EF, but may be if you remove "new" keyword you will get result, try above query without "new". but anyway why you using dataset, simply you can use EF with linq, use auto entity generator and this helps you a lot.

Comment: I'm using a dataset because i thought it would be the best thing to store information direct from a database in. would using an EF be any better? to be honest, i've never use an "EF"

Comment: IMHO Yes, EF is too much better than dataset, there are lots of reason, but in general, design and maintenance and also further imrovement is too much better via EF, but using EF is very easy, there are two ways: 1. Code First, 2.Using predefined database. in the first case (code first), you can graphically design your entities, in the second case you can use predefined database and attach your program to database, EF will generate the required entities. I'll provide some links for both cases, but for startup yuo can use your database to generate EF code.

Comment: The database is in access 2007 for development until the mysql server is up. i will need to be constantly reading and updating from the server mind. How do i generate the entity framework code in access 2007?

Comment: you don't generate EF code in database you will generate it in c#, did you read the tutorial that I linked in the answer?